# How to send multiple emails on document update trigger using cloud function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

I have created an array of objects in a document and each object has an email ID.

I want to send an email to all those email IDs. So, I'm doing that using Nodemailer in a cloud function which runs on update trigger.

I can't use the onCreate trigger as there is some update being done in the document post-creation and I was unable to get the updated changes.

So, I have set a `mailSent` value as false and I want to change it to true when the mail gets sent.

But the issue is that the function is getting triggered multiple times as the trigger is document update and I'm updating the document within the function.

Here is my function code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

const mailFrom = functions.config().mail.from;
const mailPwd = functions.config().mail.pwd;
const mailHost = functions.config().mail.host;
const mailPort = functions.config().mail.port;

exports.sendEmailNotification = functions
  .region("asia-south1")
  .firestore.document("collection/{docId}")
  .onUpdate(async (change, _) => {
    const updatedData = change.after.data();
    const updatedMembersData = updatedData["members"];
    const docId = updatedData["id"];
    let receiverMail = "";
    let partner = "";

    updatedMembersData.forEach(async (member) => {
      if (!member["mailSent"]) {
        receiverName = member["name"];
        receiverMail = member["email"];
        partner = member["partner"];
        let members = [];
        let doc = await db
          .collection("collection")
          .doc(docId)
          .get();

        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
          host: mailHost,
          port: mailPort,
          auth: {
            user: mailFrom,
            pass: mailPwd,
          },
        });

        let mailOptions = {
          from: "name@example.com",
          to: receiverMail,
          subject: "EMAIL",
          html: `<h2>MAIL TEXT</h2><h4>Hi ${receiverName}, Your partner is ${partner}</h4>`,
        };

        if (doc.exists) {
          const data = doc.data();
          members = data["members"];
          for (const updateMember of members) {
            if (updateMember["name"] === member["name"]) {
              updateMember["mailSent"] = true;
            }
          }
          db.collection("collection")
            .doc(docId)
            .update({ members: members })
            .then((_) => {
              transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
              return 0;
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log(error));
        } else {
          console.log("No such document!");
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

Any help would be great, thank you!

Comment: You're not dealing with promises correctly.  The function needs to return a single promise that becomes fulfilled when all the aync work is complete.  Calling `then` on a promise does not make the code pause and wait for completion.

Comment: @DougStevenson Can you please tell how exactly do I do that as I clearly am not aware of it now?

Comment: Following up on Doug's comment, you should try using an `await` in `db.collection("collection").doc(docId).update({ members: members })` instead of `.then()`. Let me know if this works.

Comment: @RafaelLemos thank you for the suggestion, I'll try doing this.

Comment: Ok, let me know if this fixes it.